# Retrieving data from a result set

Tags: zend-framework, html-lists

I am working on an application where I need to select comments made by individuals from a table..but am having problems retrieving data from the  result set..
This is my sql statements

```
public function get_Comments()
    {
        $select=$this->_db->select()
                      ->from('comments',array('id','comment','user_id'));
        $result=$this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select);
        return $result;
    }
```

i have received the data in my controller and action this way..
          $comments=new  Application_Model_DbTable_Procedure();
           $main_comments=$comments->get_Comments();

```
       $result=(array) $main_comments;
       print_r($result);
```

i have not yet taken the data to the view but just wanted to display it directly from the controller and then move it later..
This is the array i get

```
       Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [comment] => how is attachment in safaricom    [user_id] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [comment] => hello world [user_id] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [comment] => how is attahment in kra [user_id] => 2 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 16 [comment] => how is attachment in kra? [user_id] => 3 ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 17 [comment] => hello world [user_id] => 2 ) [5] => Array ( [id] => 18 [comment] => this is me trying everythin out [user_id] => 2 ) [6] => Array ( [id] => 19 [comment] => am testing system [user_id] => 3 ) ) 

     I wanted to get the result in three columns: 
          id       comment      user_id
```

I have tried using foreach loops but just cant get the results....am new to zend...I have tried to check for solutions in this site but can't get any that solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your function get_comments() return a fetchAll(Double array) result, that can be displayed as:
-In your controller:

```
 $main_comments=$comments->get_Comments();
$this->view->$main_comments=$main_comments;/*make the varibles avelaible to the view*/
```

-In the appropriate view:

```
<?php foreach ($this->main_comments as $item): ?>
    <?= $item['comment'] ?> 
    <?= $item['user....'] ?> <!-- Add your vars here and some HTML...  -->
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It worked....excellent....Thanks alot...When i grow up i wanna be answering peoples questions like you...Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

@Timmz,

you make an error, it's :

```
$this->view->main_comments
```

not

```
$this->view->$main_comments
```